# Can't seem to find an EOF character?

Tags: c, while-loop

**I have:**

```
    #include <stdio.h>

/* Copy input to output; 2nd version. */

main(void)
{
    int c;

    while ((c = getchar()) != EOF)
        putchar(c);
    return 0;
}
```

I want to terminate the while loop by entering an end-of-line character. 
**I Have Tried Inputing:**

```
"\t"
"\0"
%d
%f
%c
%x
%n
EOF
"EOF"
\nEOF
int
float
char
long
long long
array
1 => 10
all letters
all symbols on keyboard
 .
 .
 .
```

**Question:** What is the magical EOF character that I'm looking for?

**I am Sorry if this is a really easy question for you,but please be nice I'm only a beginner trying to learn something.*

Comment: there were already many questions about EOF in this site

Comment: @LưuVĩnhPhúc Thank you for bringing that up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On Windows, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd>;
on Linux, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd>.

Comment: But isn't there something that I can input that will terminate the program? Without using Ctl + D ?

Comment: Aren't you asking about how to input `EOF` character? Ctrl+D enters `EOF` character; of course you could also use Ctrl+C to send a signal to interrupt the program.

Comment: I think I misphrased the question. Ctrl+D does enter `EOF` character,but I don't know what character it is. If it is possible for the user to know,I want to know the character.If it's not then,that's all I was looking for and thank you for your answer. :)

Comment: Ctrl-<letter key> sends the corresponding character 1 (Ctrl-A) through 26 (Ctrl-Z).  ASCII defines "end of transmission" (EOT) as character 4, which is why *nix uses Ctrl-D for EOF.  If you're on Windows, you can type Alt-26 (using the numpad) which will show up as ^Z in your command prompt and act just as Ctrl-Z.  (EDIT: As mentioned elsewhere, in C EOF is "some negative number that can't really be a character" not a particular character that is typed in.)

Comment: @GlennTeitelbaum Yes I tried,and it was `-1` But when I input -1 the loop does not get terminated.

Comment: -1 is not a character, getchar only works with characters so the first time it'll return '-' and the second time '1'

Answer (score 1):

There is NO `EOF` character. "EOF" is a logical condition that represents "end of file" has been met.

On Linux machine, you can "signal" the standard input `EOF` condition by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> in the beginning of the line.

Windows systems reserve a character `Ctrl+Z`, which is `0x1A` in hex, to indicate this "end of file" condition. You can input this character by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd>. It is still not a real `EOF` character though. Rather, it is a convention in Windows.

Comment: EOF is not a character. getchar must return 256 possible byte values (if CHAR_BIT is 8) AND a special case, that is EOF. So getchar must return int to be enough to include 257 values

Answer (score 1):

Here ya go @Andy. You just used an int by accident instead of char c.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{   
    char c; 
    while ((c = getchar()) != '\t') // while input != tab, remember to use single 
        putchar(c);             // quotes for characters '\n' etc. 
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

If you are curious about the signals in UNIX/LINUX system this code might help, wrote it for one of my OS labs. Essentially, the program keep asking for a user input. However, when you try to quit during in the beginning with <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>z</kbd> or <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>c</kbd> it doesn't allow you to because the signal gets ignored by the parent and gets handled by the signal handlers for the child process. Note, the parent is sleeping in the beginning, but when it wakes up it kills the child process and ends the program.

```
#include <stdio.h> 
#include <signal.h>  
#include <malloc.h> 
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>

#define maxLength 1024
//****************************************
//  Signal Handlers For Child Process 
//****************************************
void ctrlchandler(){ 
    signal(SIGINT, SIG_IGN); //Ignore ctrl-c
    write(1, "Don't even think about it!", 26); 
} 

void ctrlzhandler(){ 
    signal(SIGTSTP, SIG_IGN); //Ignore ctrl-z
    write(1, "Nice Try.", 9);
}

//****************************************
//  Main Program
//****************************************
int main(int argc, char* argv[]){ 
pid_t pid; 
int status; 
//Dynamically allocate char array for input line 
char *inputLine = (char*)malloc(maxLength*sizeof(char)); 

//Ignore Ctrl-z and Ctrl-c 
signal(SIGINT, SIG_IGN); 
signal(SIGTSTP, SIG_IGN); 

//Fork Process 
if((pid = fork())<0){ 
     //If fork fails 
     printf("Fork Child Process Faild.\n"); 
}

//Parent Process 
else if(pid != 0){   
     printf("Parent: My child %d has been spawned.\n",pid);
     printf("My pid is %d\n",getpid()); 
     sleep(30); 
     kill(pid, SIGKILL); 
     if(waitpid(pid, &status, WUNTRACED))
        printf("Child %d has terminated abnormally.\n",pid); 
}

//Child Process 
else{ 
     sleep(1); //Wait for parent to output first 
     while(1){ 
        signal(SIGTSTP, ctrlzhandler);
        signal(SIGINT, ctrlchandler); 
        printf("Enter Input:"); 
        fgets(inputLine, maxLength, stdin); 
      }
}

//Free allocated char array 
free(inputLine); 
return 0; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
main()
{
        printf ("%d=%x sizeof=%d\n", EOF, EOF, sizeof(EOF));
}
```

The output is:

```
-1=ffffffff sizeof=4
```

`EOF` is not a `char`, it is an `int`

if you type the Control sequence signifying end of file - it will be translated to an `int` whose value is `-1`

Comment: Thanks for the answer.I did something similar to that and the results were also `-1`.